# Conditional SUM in Pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am using the ternary operator to include values in `SUM()` operation conditionally. Here is how I am doing it.

```
GROUPED = GROUP ALL_MERGED BY (fld1, fld2, fld3);

REPORT_DATA = FOREACH GROUPED
              {     GENERATE group,
                    SUM(GROUPED.fld4 == 'S' ? GROUPED.fld5 : 0) AS sum1,
                    SUM(GROUPED.fld4 == 'S' ? GROUPED.fld5 : (GROUPED.fld5 * -1)) AS sum2;
               }
```

Schema for `ALL_MERGED` is

```
{ALL_MERGED: {fld1:chararray, fld2:chararray, fld3:chararray, fld4:chararray: fld5:int}}
```

When I execute this, it gives me following error:

```
ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1000: Error during parsing. Invalid alias: SUM in {group: (fld1:chararray, fld2:chararray, fld3:chararray), ALL_MERGED: {fld1:chararray, fld2:chararray, fld3:chararray, fld4:chararray: fld5:int}}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

`SUM` is a UDF which takes a bag as input.  What you are doing has a number of problems, and I suspect it would help you to review a good reference on Pig.  I recommend [Programming Pig](http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9781449302641/), available for free online.  To begin with, `GROUPED` has two fields: a tuple called `group` and a bag called `ALL_MERGED`, which is what the error message is trying to tell you. (I say "trying" because Pig error messages are often quite cryptic.)

Also, you cannot pass expressions to UDFs like you wish to do.  Instead you will have to `GENERATE` these fields and then pass them afterward.  Try this:

```
ALL_MERGED_2 =
    FOREACH ALL_MERGED
    GENERATE
        fld1 .. fld5,
        ((fld4 == 'S') ? fld5 : 0) AS sum_me1,
        ((fld4 == 'S') ? fld5 : fld5*-1) AS sum_me2;

GROUPED = GROUP ALL_MERGED_2 BY (fld1, fld2, fld3);
DATA =
    FOREACH GROUPED
    GENERATE
        group,
        SUM(ALL_MERGED_2.sum_me1) AS sum1,
        SUM(ALL_MERGED_2.sum_me2) AS sum2;
```